# Can I change "delete" to "archive" in the message control bezel in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, macos

The version of Mail.app that comes with Mavericks has this cool message control bezel (below, in the orange box) under the email header in every message allowing you to delete, reply, reply-all, or forward the message when you hover on the line:

[image]

It's great, but I archive all my mail. Can I change the trash can button (pink arrow) to the archive box, like in my toolbar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by CMW, Delete2Archive can solve this issue:
http://akgungor.com/2013/11/11/delete2archive-archive-gmail-messages-using-delete-key-os-x-mavericks-mail/

I use it an can confirm that it works, also for your problem:

- When I hit delete on the keyboard it is archived (i.e. it stays in Gmails "All Mail")
- When I hit the button from your screenshot, this seems to apply as well (to my surprise). So therefore your issue should be solved as well :)
- When I hit the delete button in the toolbar of Mail.app, it gets actually deleted to the trash. You can customize the toolbar to include an "Archive" button as well (right click on the toolbar and choose 'customize toolbar'), see screenshot. I put it left from the delete button:

[image]

Comment: I had already installed and tested Delete2Archive for the delete button - I didn't realize it would also work for that button. For some reason it's not working now though, I will fiddle and then accept this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Per [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5361), the message control bezel has a fixed definition of items:

> **7**. Message control bezel – Appears when your cursor hovers over this area of the message. The controls are:
>
> - Trash – Delete the message
> - Reply – Reply to the sender of the message.
> - Reply All – Reply to the sender and all recipients of the message.
> - Forward – Forward the message to another recipient.

I've used GDB to attempt to [find a hidden preference](http://arcticmac.home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html) for this, but have been unsuccessful.

You can provide feedback for Mail suggesting the feature be added at the following Apple feedback page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately with the current version of Mail.app, that bar isn't configurable yet.

You may want to follow [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5538489?tstart=0) for a possible future solution. Or open a ticket about making that bar configurable. I'm sure a lot of people would want that.

Answer (score -3):

Im actually using Mavericks. And YES, its configurable. In my case i touch the trash symbol with 2 fingers and i get the option to change or add the archive icon.

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot showing this?

Comment: Seems not to be working for me

Comment: Are you talking about the icons in the *toolbar*, as in koelnek's screenshot, or the icons that appear *inside the message itself*, per the OP's screenshot? The former can be modified as you describe, but I don't get any options when right-clicking the latter in Mavericks.